# Importing eventlet SSL results in: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenSSL.tsafe'

Tags: python-3.x, pyopenssl, eventlet

Why am I getting the following import error when I try to import eventlet's SSL module:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenSSL.tsafe'
```

Is eventlet's OpenSSL not compatible with recent versions of pyOpenSSL?

**Reproduction Steps**

Using the following Pipenv:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"

[packages]
pyOpenSSL = "*"
eventlet = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3"
```

Create a pipenv using that file:

```
$ pipenv install
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Pipfile: /tmp/Pipfile
Using /usr/local/bin/python3.8 (3.8.3) to create virtualenv…
...
Successfully created virtual environment! 
...
```

Now import eventlet.green.OpenSSL.SSL:

```
$ pipenv run python
Python 3.8.3 (default, Jun 29 2020, 18:02:49) 
[GCC 8.3.1 20190311 (Red Hat 8.3.1-3)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from eventlet.green.OpenSSL import SSL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/myuser/.local/share/virtualenvs/tmp-XVr6zr33/lib/python3.8/site-packages/eventlet/green/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import tsafe
  File "/home/myuser/.local/share/virtualenvs/tmp-XVr6zr33/lib/python3.8/site-packages/eventlet/green/OpenSSL/tsafe.py", line 1, in <module>
    from OpenSSL.tsafe import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenSSL.tsafe'
>>>
```

Comment: Hmmm. Digging into the packages, I notice that PyOpenSSL just created a 20.0.0 release which removed tsafe.py. Maybe eventlet needs an update?

Answer (score 0):

After digging around a while, it looks like eventlet indeed does not currently work with the latest 20.0.0 PyOpenSSL package which was released four days ago as of the time of this post. I filed an issue with eventlet:

https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/issues/671

Until eventlet is updated, we'll have to pin PyOpenSSL to the previous 19.1.0 release (per the Pipfile from the question):

```
pyOpenSSL = "==19.1.0"
```